What's the meaning of "QTY"?
I found the abbreviation "QTY" in an assay (not essay!). Can you tell me the meaning of this abbreviation? How can I paraphrase/explain it into ordinary words?

Context, and again context...

Tags are wrong: single-word-request, etymology, word-choice.

QTY is the abbreviation for Quantity. You can check it here  https://www.dictionary.com/browse/qty
You can simply write it as quantity. Hope it helped 

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

While it is easy to see how qty could be used as an abbreviation for quantity, it seems very odd that somebody who wanted to use it for that purpose would write it in all capitals, which is what the OP encountered.
